# Remove facebook like using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Using GET https://graph.facebook.com/288095787880494/likes/159222380758097 returns me

```
{
 "data": [
  {
   "name": "Vote For Prophet Hazrat Muhmmad (PBUH) the best man of world",
   "category": "Cause",
   "id": "159222380758097"
  }
],
"paging": {
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/288095787880494/likes/159222380758097?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=159222380758097"
}
}
```

Now i want to remove this like. How do I do that? When I use HTTP Delete I get the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
   "message": "(#3) App must be on whitelist",
   "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to remove `likes` for Facebook Pages. Only for `post`, `comment` and URL's owned by your application.

To be able to do this your application must be **whitelisted by Facebook** which can only be done by contacting Facebook directly (and will probably require some kind of agreement and cost you money as well...)

Comment: Well the reason I wanted to do this is that I have a cause added to my fanpage like shown above. Now I am unable to remove it from the page. Do you have any idea as to how that can be done?

Comment: Go to [that Facebook Page](http://facebook.com/288095787880494) or place it's URL in [Like Box social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) generator and press "Unlike"

Comment: Unable to do that! It says I need to switch back to my Username in order to do that though as I mentioned earlier this link has been liked by the Page

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe two issues.  Maybe the same.  But try what I suggest in #2.  Maybe facebook is spitting out a false/misleading error message.

1. Your app and or page is currently on the facebook naughty list. "*Error code: (#3) App must be on whitelist*"
2. You need to use a PAGE access token and not a USER access token. "*It says I need to switch back to my Username in order to do that though as I mentioned earlier this link has been liked by the Page*"

Comment: I am using Page Access Code. And number one can't be true. It's a new app id

Comment: using the same token, does `https://graph.facebook.com/288095787880494/likes/159222380758097` return the same thing as `https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/159222380758097`